# Why does Angular ng-message 'when="required"' fire even though the input field has input?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a [plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/jPAALWTtgE6kOkN6u0JV?p=preview).

When I type in input in the input field and click elsewhere on the page the message "This field is required." gets displayed.  Why is the message being displayed despite the input field having a value?

Here is the code:

```
<form name="reportform" novalidate >
  <input name="startdate" placeholder="Enter a start date" ng-model="startdatevalue" required>
  <ng-messages ng-if='reportform.startdate.$touched' for="reportform.startdate.$error">
    <ng-message when="required">
      This field is required.
    </ng-message>
  </ng-messages>
  <button ng-disabled="reportform.$invalid" type="submit">
    Submit Query
  </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing to import the ngMessages module:

example: https://plnkr.co/edit/VWhrTIzRjkQBGfjaj5Zb?p=preview

```
 var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngMessages']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});
```

Comment: D'oh, thanks.  Sorry about asking such a stupid question.  I had a much longer example that I was working on and was trying to pare it down to the essentials to post as a plunker, but apparently I removed too much code :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [updated Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/uAZWqbTk6FOlJf5LwXec?p=preview)

Only change is you need to add the dependency `ngMessages` in your angular module as

```
 var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngMessages']);

 app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.name = 'World';
 });
```